# Unable to locate element in Selenium Python (not able to find frame for the element)

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am unable to locate the element using selenium.
I have searched and found that there are frames and by changing frame i can get the element.
But in my case I'm unable to find the frame.
I have searched the whole html but was unable to find the frame only could locate the form.

Here is the code snippet which i have edited to get a rough idea :-

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse"> ==$0
      <div class="nav nabar-right">==$0
             <div class="navpage-header-content">
                        <form target="gsft_main" role="search" action="text_search_exact_match.do" aria-label="Global Search" class="form-inline navpage-global-search ng-non-bindable" method="GET">
                          <div class="input-group-transparent">
                          <input id="sysparm_search" placeholder="Search" class="form-control form-control-search" type="search"name="sysparm_search">
                          <label for="sysparm_search" title="Search" data-original-title="Search">
                           <span class="input-group-addon-transparent icon- search sysparm-search-icon"></span>
                           </label>
                           </div>
                           </form>
                 </div>
```

My element id is sysparm_search.
It's same as the search bar of stack overflow and located in the same area.

i have tried with

```
wait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it("gsft_main"))  
element3=driver.find_element_by_id("sysparm_search")
```

but not getting the element:
The error is:- Unable to locate element:

Comment: In your html the id is `sysparm_search` and in your code snippet you have `spysparm_search`. Is that the issue?

Comment: ohhhh shit just a sec i'll check

Comment: Thnx for correcting it but the issue is still there....

Comment: Does the error occur on the line where you search for the `sysparm_search` or on the line where you switch to `gsft_main`?

Comment: when I'm searching for the sysparm_search

Comment: Oh wait, I now see that `gsft_main` is a form element. That is not a `<frame>` that you would need to switch to. Though I do find it weird that it doesn't throw an exception about that...
Is there a `<frame>` element on the page?

Comment: There is an iframe with the id gsft_main.but the element does not belongs to it so i tried removing this wait command still I'm getting the error

Comment: @Bob thnx for you efforts man......Appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

I was searching and here is what i got.
The element is there but the main problem was that as after login i was been redirected to this page. The script went on. so i was not able to find it.

The workarond i used was i made the script wait untill i found the element by this command.

```
wait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "sysparm_search")))
```

Hope it helps someone.....